# How to make correct file save in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

The idea is when user starts the loop program, it must generate a file, and save some data to it. So, the user enters the number, select a directory, and then the program starts. But there is some problem on every count of loop. It is asking to select a directory again, and then it goes on TypeError.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import os
import datetime
import csv
import threading


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(master, padding='5 5 10 10')
        self.mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=N + S + W + E)
        self.measureFrame()
        self.connectionConf()
        self.meas()

    def connectionConf(self):
        self.confFrame = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe, padding='5 5 10 10').grid(column=0, row=3)
        self.confFreq = Label(self.confFrame, text='Number:')
        self.confFreq.grid(column=1, row=4, pady=5, stick=W)
        self.freqSet = Entry(self.confFrame, width=6)
        self.freqSet.grid(column=2, row=4, pady=5, stick=W)

    def measureFrame(self):
        self.name = StringVar()
        self.mesFrame = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe, padding='5 5 10 10').grid(column=0, row=5)
        self.mesHeader = Label(self.mesFrame, text='Path to save', font=10).grid(column=1, row=5, columnspan=2
                                                                                         , pady=10, stick=W)
        self.ent1 = Entry(self.mesFrame, textvariable=self.name, width=50)
        self.ent1.grid(column=1, row=7, columnspan=3, pady=5, stick=W)
        self.button1 = Button(self.mesFrame, text='Open', command=self.browseButton)
        self.button1.grid(column=4, row=7, pady=5, stick=W)

    def browseButton(self):
        filedir = filedialog.askdirectory()
        filedir = self.name.set(filedir)
        return filedir

    def meas(self):
        self.mesframe = ttk.Frame(self.mainframe, padding='5 5 10 10').grid(column=0, row=8)
        self.startb = Button(self.mesframe, text='Start',
                             command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=self.startMeas).start())
        self.startb.grid(column=1, row=10, pady=5, stick=W)

    def filename_gen(self):
        basename = self.freqSet.get()
        suffix = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S')
        filetype = '.csv'
        genfile = '_'.join([suffix, basename, filetype])
        ressfile = os.path.join(self.browseButton(), genfile)
        return ressfile

    def startMeas(self):
        with open(self.filename_gen(), 'a', newline='') as marks_csv:
            cur_mark = 'None'
            marks_wr = csv.writer(marks_csv)
            marks_wr.writerow(cur_mark)
        self.after(1000, self.startMeas)


window = Tk()
window.geometry('700x600')
app = Application(master=window)
app.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
app.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
app.mainloop()
window.quit()
```

Comment: From loop you main main `app.loop()` thing?

Comment: No, its .after() loop.

Comment: When you call startMeas for the first time, its kinda gets in a recursive timed loop. So every call starts its own timer and then it becomes chaotic since every timer starts more calls who then start their own timer.

Comment: Though I have to check up on that, but i am pretty sure that's your problem.

Comment: Well, though that wasn't the main problem (Read my answer below), I still think you should take a look at the recursive thingy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At line number 53, you're calling `self.browsebutton` again, **instead** replace it with `self.name.get()` and you code works fine.

The prolem is that you're calling that function again instead of using the preset name which is already stored in the string var from the last time you choose the directory.

What i mean is, this line:

> `ressfile = os.path.join(self.browsebutton(), genfile)`

Should be replace with:

> `ressfile = os.path.join(self.name.get(), genfile)`

Comment: Thanks! That help me. But now I face with other problem. Its create a new file on every count of loop instead to write in one file. I guess I need to call `filename_gen()` the other way.

Comment: Glad it helped you,  and try to solve that above problem yourself first then if that doesn't works out for ya, you're welcome to ask a question back again, or even extend this thread but i wouldn't recommend that.